# Setting sound output device per program

Tags: audio

I have 2 sound output devices - digital and regular aux.

When I want to change the audio output from aux to digital (headphones) the sound of the application is still going through the aux although I changed the default audio device. Which means I have to restart the application to make the sound go through the headphones.

Anyway to see which application's sound go through which device and change it without having to restart the program?

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows 7? You can view the outputs by click on the sound icon in the taskbar, and then clicking `Mixer` for the appropriate output device.

Comment: Thats that I am doing. I see my desired application at the aux but I want to transfer it to digital, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can. I suspect most applications bind to the default audio device, so when that changes, windows can automatically change them, but some applications look up the default audio device, and then bind to that device specifically. Because it's bound to a specific device and not "default", windows doesn't know to switch it. Just a guess though.